# Can Solace VPN Bridge be used to convert from one-to-many pub/sub to DTO pub/sub?

Tags: solace

Solace allows message VPN bridge with DTO (Deliver-To-One) priority.  Just wonder whether it is possible to use this feature to bridge messages published with one-to-many pub/sub model (such as MQTT) to one VPN to another VPN using DTO priority, and thus "converting" from one-to-many pub/sub model to one-to-one pub sub model.  I doubt so as the original messages are not published as DTO messages in the first place.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN Bridge will publish messages to the destination message-vpn with the same settings as it was published on the source, eg:

A message published on the source message-vpn on topic 'a/b/c' with DTO=false, will be re-published to the destination message-vpn on the same topic 'a/b/c' with the same setting DTO=false. This is assuming you have a VPN bridge set up between the source and destination message-vpns, and configured with a remote-subscription of 'a/b/c'.

The DTO configuration on a VPN bridge is used to determine the priority that its topic subscriptions have for receiving messages that were published as Deliver-To-One on the source Message VPN. You can get more information on configuring DTO on a VPN bridge [here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-VPN-Bridges.htm?Highlight=VPN%20bridge#Config-Remote-DTO)

If you want the VPN bridge to receive all messages matching its topic subscriptions, irrespective of its DTO setting, you'll want to set this to "DA"